# R: How can I reimport the data frame exactly like it was before exporting? I.e., "Saving" variable labels, object types, factor ordering etc

Tags: r, dataframe, import, type-conversion, export

I cleaned a data frame of 300+ variables and approx. 2000 rows.

When I was done, I exported the data set with the function `export(df, "SomeName.xlsx")` of the package `rio`.

Now, when I reimport the data set either via `import("SomeName.xlsx")` of `rio` or via `read_xlsx` of `readxl` two to three very important features are gone (there may be more surprises, but these are the most striking):

1. All the variable labels I assigned
2. All factors (unordered and ordered) are now characters
3. And with 2), the order of the factor levels are also gone

I could reproduce everything by running the script. However, I would like to reimport the data set exactly like it was before the export. Is this possible?

Edit: I don't need a specific file format (like .xlsx), this was an arbitrary choice of mine. So I am up for all formats that I can load and work with in R.

Comment: You are saving to an `xlsx` file which is an Excel file. Excel doesn't have any concepts of factors or levels. If you want to reload the data into R, use something like `saveRDS` to save the R object to a file and load it later with `readRDS`. If you need to be able to use it in Excel, there's not really much you can do about that. You'll likely have to save two different copies of the data (one for Excel, one for R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is the reuse the data in another R session you can use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`.

```
# save
saveRDS(df, "filename.rds")

# read
readRDS("filenmame.rds")
```

There are also `save()` and `load()` for saving and loading more than one R object. In most cases `saveRDS()` is the better choice. [Here is a blogpost](https://yihui.org/en/2017/12/save-vs-saverds/) that discusses `save()` vs. `saveRDS()`.